# c# - RegisterConditional Ninject Equivalent

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

I use Simple Injector in me project. So I Have next code:

```
container.RegisterConditional(
    typeof(ISearchService<>), 
    typeof(SearchService<>), 
    c => !c.Handled);
```

But I want to use Ninject. So what is an equivalent of this code if I'll use Ninject?

Comment: what is the relevance/meaning of `c.Handled`?

Comment: It's a bool property in `public sealed class PredicateContext`

Comment: Yes, but what's the meaning? I don't know Simple Injector, but I do know Ninject. If you can tell me what the `RegisterConditional` with `!c.Handled` mean, I might be able to help you...

Comment: Please describe what it is you'd like to achieve. A registration using `!c.Handled` never stands on itself. You will have to provide more context.